# How can I get maximum and minimum values in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL, and I'm looking for a way to get the global maximum and minimum values (for the whole table) from two columns (for example, `posx` and `posy`), using only one query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple:

```
SELECT MIN(posx), MIN(posy), MAX(posx), MAX(posy) FROM table
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    MIN(colx) AS minimum,
    MAX(colx) AS maximum,
    MIN(coly) AS minimum,
    MAX(coly) AS maximum
FROM table
```

Answer (score 4):

It's really no more complex than it sounds.

```
SELECT MIN(posx), MAX(posx), MIN(posy), MAX(posy)
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 select max(posx), min(posy) from table
```