# How to find min and max value in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a sample code:
table

```
users(id, name)
     (1, "A")
     (2, "B")
     (3, "C")
     (4, "D")
     (5, "E")
```

And table

```
points(user_id, key, value)
      (1, 'point', 300)
      (2, 'point', 200)
      (3, 'point', 500)
      (4, 'point', 100)
      (5, 'point', 600)
```

And my query

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.name, p,value AS point
            FROM users u
            JOIN points p ON ( u.id = p.user_id ) AND p.key = 'point'
            WHERE p.value > 300 AND p.value < 300
            GROUP BY u.id";
```

Result show all value, But how to get only value in MAX < x < MIN ?

```
(2, 'B', 200)
(1, 'A', 300)
(3, 'C', 500)
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE false` is equivalent to MAX < x < MIN. SCNR

Comment: There are no values where MAX < x and x < MIN.  Do you actually mean, MIN < x and x < MAX.

Comment: mean: if user x have point is 300, how to find value last max 300, and last min 300

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here [How can I get maximum and minimum values in a single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702763/how-can-i-get-maximum-and-minimum-values-in-a-single-query). SQL has MIN(x) and MAX(x) operators you can use.

Comment: But I only get value max and min when have value of x

Comment: I don't think OP is asking for the extrema of a table. In fact I have no glue what he's actually asking.